# Using jsMath in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to use jsMath to display equations in an Android application.

I started by downloading jsMath to my assets folder. Next, I created a simple index.html with the following text:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jsMath\easy\load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
       Some inline math: $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or \(ax^2+bx+c\)
    </center>
</body> 
</html>
```

In my Android application, I use a WebView to display this page.

```
 WebView wView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
 wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Unfortunately, the WebView in Android displays the text verbatim, rather than the formatted equation that I expect.  What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/jsMath/easy/load.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mike.  I tried that, but it still doesn't work.